# Ginger drink question

Tags: ginger, dietary-restriction, low-sugar

```
    7 ounces fresh ginger
    2 cups water
    3⁄4 cup granulated sugar
    lime wedge (to garnish)
    ice (garnish)
    sparkling water (to taste)
```

peel the ginger and cut into thin slices.
        boil the ginger slices in a pot with water and sugar and let boil for 10 minutes. stir every now and then. set the pot aside and let the mixture cool completely.
        strain the drink and dilute with mineral water to desired sweetness.
        serve with lime and ice.

My question is how do I make this recipe very low sugar?

Comment: What does diabetic-friendly mean to you? Low/no sugar? If so, is there any reason a sugar substitute wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Very low sugar @Cascabel and not everyone will have sugar substitute anyway

Comment: Well, it's your question. What are *you* okay with? Are sugar substitutes an option or not? If yes, is there some reason you think they won't work? If not, what are your goals, since you won't be able to make it sweet without a sweetener?

Comment: Sugar substitute is fine with me @Cascabel  but I’m trying to make it work for as many people as possible.

Comment: Okay, so a few things seem quite obvious: you can replace sugar with a non-sugar sweetener/sugar substitute, and if you omit the sugar and don't add a substitute, it won't be sweet anymore and won't be the same drink. Given that, what else do you want to know?

Comment: Sugar substitutes would probably be okay with me.

Comment: Okay, so... that's fine, but we probably don't need a copy of "what can I substitute for sugar that's not sugar?" for every recipe out there. I don't think we're really providing much knowledge with questions like that.

Comment: I've posted https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/91157/1672 to try to more generally cover these sorts of questions, in a way that'll hopefully be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sugar substitute of your choice added after heating and cooling (all you need is for it to dissolve), in an amount meant to replace 3/4 cup of sugar, or just adjust it until it's as sweet as you'd like.

Comment: Not all sugar substitutes are heat friendly.

Comment: @DebbieM. Okay, amended - not really an issue here.